# AsyncTaskLoader and orienatation change

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have an AsyncTaskLoader to do some work on the first startup. The loader is initialized in the OnCreate method of my Activity.

```
if(!startedLoader) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(INITIALIZE_DB_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    startedLoader = true;
}
```

startedLoader is a boolean that is kept in onSaveInstanceState and retrieved again in onCreate.

This avoids my loader to restart. But now it does not deliver the results through the callbacks because my listener, which is my activity itself, was destroyed.
Here's the code that starts my Loader:

```
@Override
public Loader<Boolean> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new InitalizeDatabaseLoader(this);
}
```

How can I avoid my AsyncTaskLoader to restart on an orientation change but still deliver the results?

Comment: You can't, Cancel the asynctask process, start it again over orientation changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to extend the `deliverResult()` method and keep the result in memory until the activity reconnects to the loader.

You can find here a pretty good example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

The essential part is:

```
/**
 * Called when there is new data to deliver to the client.  The
 * super class will take care of delivering it; the implementation
 * here just adds a little more logic.
 */
@Override public void deliverResult(List<AppEntry> apps) {
    if (isReset()) {
        // An async query came in while the loader is stopped.  We
        // don't need the result.
        if (apps != null) {
            onReleaseResources(apps);
        }
    }
    List<AppEntry> oldApps = mApps;
    mApps = apps;

    if (isStarted()) {
        // If the Loader is currently started, we can immediately
        // deliver its results.
        super.deliverResult(apps);
    }

    // At this point we can release the resources associated with
    // 'oldApps' if needed; now that the new result is delivered we
    // know that it is no longer in use.
    if (oldApps != null) {
        onReleaseResources(oldApps);
    }
}
```

Also, you will want to extend the `onStartLoading()` method, in order to deliver the cached result right away:

```
/**
 * Handles a request to start the Loader.
 */
@Override protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mApps != null) {
        // If we currently have a result available, deliver it
        // immediately.
        deliverResult(mApps);
    }

    // Start watching for changes in the app data.
    if (mPackageObserver == null) {
        mPackageObserver = new PackageIntentReceiver(this);
    }

    // Has something interesting in the configuration changed since we
    // last built the app list?
    boolean configChange = mLastConfig.applyNewConfig(getContext().getResources());

    if (takeContentChanged() || mApps == null || configChange) {
        // If the data has changed since the last time it was loaded
        // or is not currently available, start a load.
        forceLoad();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer but i'll delete the question. The behaviour i wanted was already working, my bad...
FYI, when calling forceLoad() in onStartLoading(), it will check whether it's already running or not. It won't restart the loadInBackground() method but will deliver to the new listener, my recreated activity.